# Координаты точки на прямой

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Задача следующая:
есть луч, который идет из начала координат
есть координаты точки А (x, y, z) на этом луче
необходимо найти координаты точки, находящейся на данном луче на некотором расстоянии r от точки А.

Как я решаю данную задачу:
1. нахожу вектор с координатами {x, y, z} (вектор в точку А из начала координат)
2. нахожу длину вектора и делю его координаты на полученную длину, таким образом получаю единичный вектор
3. далее умножаю координаты вектора на расстояние r, на котором располагается искомая точка 
4. к полученным координатам прибавляю координаты точки А

Подскажите, насколько решение корректно?

Comment: Все корректно, только в условии задачи не сказано, в каком направлении надо откладывать расстояние `r` от точки `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно даже в аналитическом виде :) - если координаты точки A (xa, ya, za), то искомых точек две, и их координаты -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А всерьез, по вопросу - второй ответ можно получить также, вычитая из координат точки A полученный вектор - если его длина не превышает расстояния точки A от начала координат, конечно (т.к. в условии - "луч", а не "прямая").